# WCF - Create client programmatically only from endpoint name

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-endpoint, wcf-configuration

My WCF client can connect to several endpoints. But they all have different addresses, bindings and contracts. So my question is : How can I create my WCF client programmatically depending just of the name of my endpoint I want to connect to (which I have in my code)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, I believe this is the answer [using IPC, can be easily converted to other communication types]

Listener:

```
_host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ContractClass));
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IContract), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/" + listenerEndpointName));
_host.Open();
```

Client:

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/" + listenerEndpointName));
IContract proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Comment: I'm just talking about the client, not the server. On the client code, I do not have the type of contract. It may be different depending of the endpoint

Comment: So simply add a `switch` statement which will determine the `type` that will be delivered to the factory

Comment: I thought about this. But there is no answer using wcf or .net? I mean there is no .net class that can do this thing?

Comment: What do you mean? the above is WCF,NET solution

Comment: The ChannelFactory class cannot create proxy client just with the endpoint name?

Comment: ChannelFactory must know interface, binding and address. Take a look at HttpClient class if you're using http binding